# Dystopian future where a machine erases memories, and removes hair and nails

Tags: story-identification, books, dystopia

There's a book I read about a year ago that was absolutely amazing and I've recently been looking with all that I can remember about the book. The books in a dystopian universe where the main character gets captured, tortured by a machine that also slowly erases the main characters' memories.

The machine also removes all the hair and nails from the characters body and feeds them through a tube in his stomach, then the character communicates with a rebel organization who releases them from control of the computer. That's most all of what I can remember, if anyone can help me you'd be my savior.

Also if you have anymore questions about the plot I would be more than happy to tell you all I can remember

Comment: The rebel organization releases "them" from control of the computer? Who or what is "them"? The main character's hair and nails? Oh, and who or what is the computer feeding through a tube in his stomach?

Comment: That was a mistake on my part, when i said "them" i am referring to the main character, the organization basically turns off the computer and allows the main character to recover and try to escape there "cage" which appears to be a room with white walls and no apparent windows or doors

Comment: oh my gosh. Some thought niggling at the back of my head, I know what this is... On another topic, I know its wrong entirely, but the machine sounds like that of the young adult/child series "The Mysterious Benedict Society". Maybe the author of the aforementioned series got inspiration from the book you read?